# What are the different usages of the word "strike"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

I read this word in many many contexts, but I can't understant the different usages of it. The only usage I really understant is that the follows:

To strike is to attack another country using millitary forces (troops) specially.

My question is, are there other usages? Could you give an example or two for each?

Comment: This is really much too broad a question: the old [***OED***](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt109murruoft#page/1124/mode/2up), 90 years ago, already had **32 columns** of definitions and citations for *strike*! And as that suggests, this is exactly the sort of question which a good dictionary is designed to answer. Try [**this site**](http://www.onelook.com/?loc=pub&w=strike), which gives you links to many dictionaries.

Comment: @StoneyB , What about today usage of the word ? I need the most used usages not every possible one!

Comment: ...or [this site](https://www.wordnik.com/words/strike) which lists several definitions. You can strike up a conversation, strike a match, or strike up a tune; the labor union can go on strike when the clock strikes midnight –   not to mention getting a strike in baseball or bowling. This word does not have a predominant usage. Perhaps you could provide a context where you saw it, and couldn't understand what it meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a learner's dictionary. For example, here is *strike* from the Cambridge Learner's Dictionary:

- [strike](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/strike_1) (verb)
- [strike](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/strike_2) (noun)

Those links will give you the most important definitions and some example sentences.